# The proof of Frobenius Formula in Fulton and Harris "representation theory a first course" .

Tags: proof-verification, reference-request, representation-theory, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups

I was reading the proof of Frobenius Formula in Fulton and Harris "representation theory a first course", but it was hard to me to follow the book, can anyone recommend a better source for me that contains more details and examples?

Comment: What specific formula? Have you looked in the [CS/S/T book](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/representation-theory-of-the-symmetric-groups-the-okounkov-vershik-approach-character-formulas-and)?

Comment: I think (if I understand correctly )he is trying to prove the formula in p.49 , in pages 54-62 .............. so I am speaking about the formula in page 49 @darijgrinberg

Comment: Please make sure to ask your question in a way that can be understood without having the book at hand.

Comment: I am sorry @darijgrinberg I think I am speaking about Frobenius character formula

Comment: There is a whole section (§4.2) devoted to "The Frobenius character formula" in the CS/S/T book I've linked (and that's a book that tries to be fairly detailed and self-contained). Problem is, different people call fairly different things the "Frobenius character formula", so this may and may not be it.

Comment: If you want Fulton and Harris book I can email it for you ..... so that youcan see the pages I am speaking about ..... I do not know how to attach a file on this site @darijgrinberg

Comment: The issue is not about me not having the book (I have it), but about posting questions that require the reader to look up a book they might not have (and, before you commented, finding something inside the book). There are several things you can do in order to make it easier for us to answer your question -- quote the statement of the formula, explain the notation. The answerers shouldn't have to do the whole job!

Comment: I am sorry @darijgrinberg  I will try to follow your advice as much as  can.